# Builder for setters and getters

Tags: java

I want use this Java code in order to create Java Object:

```
public class NotificationMessage implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 985577913631100757L;

    private int id;
    private String uniqueid;
    private String status;
    private String type;
    private Map<String, String> map;
    private Date created_at;

    public NotificationMessage() {
    }

    public NotificationMessage(int id, String uniqueid, String status, String type, Map<String, String> map,
            Date created_at) {
        this.id = id;
        this.uniqueid = uniqueid;
        this.status = status;
        this.type = type;
        this.map = map;
        this.created_at = created_at;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
....
}
```

How I can use builder in order to minimize setters when I want to create Java object?

I want to set values like this:

```
NotificationMessage.builder().id(123).uniqueid(1234).status("active")
```

Comment: what is "builder"? Are you looking for the IDE functionnality to auto create the getters/setters?

Comment: Do you mean the builder pattern or do you want to use a `StringBuilder`?

Comment: What do you mean by "minimize setters"?

Comment: with a builder, you'll have the same amount of setters, you just move them to another class

Comment: Please see the updated post.

Comment: You use builder by doing some research on what that is.

Answer (score 2):

You can use
https://projectlombok.org/

```
@Entity
@Data
@Builder
@Getter
public class NotificationMessage {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String uniqueid;
    private String status;
    private String type;
    private Map<String, String> map;
    private Date created_at;
}


NotificationMessage.builder().id(123).uniqueid(1234).status("active");

assertThat(NotificationMessage.getId()).isEqulTo(123));
```

Comment: Is there any solution like the above?

Comment: Sure, add `@Builder` to the class

Answer (score 0):

In order to chain the method calls like that:

```
NotificationMessage.builder().id(123).uniqueid(1234).status("active")
```

You have to return the calling object (`this`) on each call:

```
public NotificationMessage id(int id) {
    this.id = id;
    return this;
}
```

Comment: You are missing the crucial point: he doesn't understand what a Builder is, and what a (to be written method) `builder()` would return.

Comment: @jhamon this approach will make the java Object really fat. Is there other way to implement it?

Comment: You need to either write the builder manually or use a code-generating library like [Google AutoValue](https://github.com/google/auto/blob/master/value/userguide/index.md) or Project Lombok as explained in the other answer.